# Is there a syntax to describe whether a value is between two other values? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For example (conceptual code, not working):

```
BooleanVariable = (Y <= X < Z)
```

instead of

```
BooleanVariable = (X >= Y) and (X < Z)
```

(I tried to find it in the Manual first. :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such syntax at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't you Pine Script Prophets think in a Node System? 